# ES6 modules import is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out an issue I have with ES6 modules import.

This is a very simplified version of what I'm attempting to do. My current file structure is much more complicated with nested folders.

I have 2 ReactJS components:

```
/buttons
  /MyComponent1.js
  /index.js
/texts
  /MyComponent2.js
  /index.js

/index.js
```

My files look something like this:

I'm importing the `MyComponent2` from the root `index.js` file which is the entry-point of my package.

**MyComponent1.js**

```
import MyComponent2 from '../../';

export default () => (
  <div><MyComponent2 /></div>
);
```

**MyComponent2.js**

```
export default () => (
  <div>Hello world</div>
);
```

My `buttons/index.js` and `texts/index.js` files export all components in their own folder:

**buttons/index.js**

```
export { default as MyComponent1 } from './MyComponent1';
```

**texts/index.js**

```
export { default as MyComponent2 } from './MyComponent2';
```

And my root `index.js` export all my folders to make them publicly available. It's my entry-point:

```
export * from './buttons';
export * from './texts';
```

So when I import `MyComponent2` in `MyComponent1` from the root `index.js` file, it's `undefined`. When I import it from `./MyComponent2.js`, it's defined. When I import the entire package in another project and import `MyComponent2` from the root `index.js` file, it's defined.

It's mind-blowing and I don't understand why I can't import `MyComponent2` from the root `index.js` file.

I need to do that because I have a set of hundred of components nested in different folder and I want to make them all available from this entry-point file.

Can someone tell me what is happening and how to make this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Try simple to export: `export default MyComponent1`

To import: `import MyComponent1 from './index'`

Comment: I found importing to vars then exporting separately worked. This way didn't.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, took me a while to figure out what is happening. Please take a look at the sandbox i've setup - https://codesandbox.io/s/nk0qmo096j

> I've tried to keep the folder/module structure similar to what you've described. Please look through how the folder/modules are structured before you continue reading.

When you run the code in the sandbox, take a look at the console. You'll see something like this -

[image]

So let me try to explain why what you're trying to do is not working

1. `buttons/MyComponent` is the first file to be "exported" (since its at the bottom of the dependency chain; Project/index -> components/index -> buttons/index -> buttons/MyComponent)

> Note that `components/index` has not been exported yet, so it will return undefined

2. Then `buttons/index` is exported, followed by `texts/index`
3. Then `buttons/MyComponent` is rendered; just before it is rendered i manually `require` `components/index` and it is now defined so returns some defined value

In essence, when your `MyComponent1` is trying to import `MyComponent2` via the `index` file, the `index` file has not been exported yet so it returns undefined. To work around this, you have to `require` `MyComponent2` from within `MyComponent1`'s render method.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. It really helps! Although importing from a render method, that's quite ugly haha! I'm open to other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

you can import all the components from the respective component files and then assign them to a variable in the root component and then export all of them as objects.

`import MyComponent1 from './buttons/index'`

`import MyComponent2 from './texts/index'`

`export {MyComponent1, MyComponent2}`

to import this components in another file or project. you could import only one them using object destructuring.

`import {MyComponent1} from 'index.js'`

`import {MyComponent2} from 'index.js'`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had an old `js` file that the IDE imported instead of the updated `ts` file. so if your module file is `module.js` make sure there isn't a compiled old `module.js` in the same directory